# Condition for subgroup lattice of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ to be a straight line

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was asked what was the condition(s) on n for the lattice subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ to be a straight line (ie each subgroup is a subgroup of another).

Then the order of each subgroup divides the order of the one it is included in.

So I first answered the condition was that n is prime($\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is then a simple group). It works but there are some n in $\mathbb{N}$ having this property anyway : $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ for instance, ( $<2>$ and the identity) , and $4$ is not prime.

Then I tried to draw the subgroups lattice of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ for several n and it seems like the condition on n is that is has to be divisible by only one prime ($\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ and 3, $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ and 4, $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ and 5)

Any hints ? Am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: $n=p^m$. Indeed, if $p,q|n, \ p\ne q$ then $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_q$ cannot be included in a common chain.

Comment: Thanks for this ! does it work for every cyclic group then?(as they are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ ?

Comment: Of course. I considered $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_q$ as subgroups in  $\mathbb{Z}_n$.